# Custom plugin - load enqueue only for this plugin

Tags: plugins, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

I have made my own plugin, which works fine, but I'm enqueueing (is that a word?) bootstrap, which then loads cross-site (admin). I found some workarounds, but the current workaround I'm trying throws an error (except on the plugin admin page itself).

Here's the code in myplugin/myplugin.php

```
class enq {     
function enqueue($hook) {
    if ((class_exists('myPlugin')) && ($_GET['page'] == 'myplugin')) {
        wp_enqueue_style('zsvstyle', plugins_url('/assets/app.min.css', __FILE__));
        wp_enqueue_style('perfect-scrollbar', plugins_url('assets/lib/perfect-scrollbar/css/perfect-scrollbar.min.css', __FILE__));
        wp_enqueue_style('iconic-font', plugins_url('assets/lib/material-design-icons/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css', __FILE__));
        wp_enqueue_script('zsvscript', plugins_url('/assets/app.min.js', __FILE__));
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery', 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js', array(), null, true);
    }
}
}

function scripts() {
    add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'enqueue'));
}

if (class_exists('myPlugin')) {

    $enq = new enq;
    $enq->scripts();

}
```

The error is

Notice: Undefined index: page in /var/www/html/mysite/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/myplugin.php on line 63

What is the correct way to only load the enqueue in the admin for this one plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WordPress documentation for [admin_enqueue_scripts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts) says that you can:

```
function load_custom_wp_admin_style($hook) {
        // Load only on ?page=mypluginname
        if($hook != 'toplevel_page_mypluginname') {
                return;
        }
        wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_wp_admin_css', plugins_url('admin-style.css', __FILE__) );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_custom_wp_admin_style' );
```

Basically, you're being passed `$hook` and it should be the value of your page name, which is the name you've chosen.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this in my testing, but the problem was that I was using `if($hook != 'mypluginname')`, because I thought that `toplevel_page_` was a description, but it has to be included.

I now echoed `$hook` and of course it returned `toplevel_page_myplugin` (in my case).